# How can I change the value of an NSImage?

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginning Objective-C programming programmer, and I want to change the value of an NSImage. That means that if I have an NSImage that is a NSStatusUnavaliable, how could I make it a NSStatusAvaliable? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  Google "NSStatusUnavailable".  About the 3rd hit will be the Apple doc for NSImage.  If you search that page for "StatusUnavailable" you'll be taken to a list of NSString constants, including both the Unavailable and Available ones, and the line above the list explains that they can be used with `imageNamed:`.  So a simple Google search has found everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I believe what you're asking is:  Somewhere you have an NSImage instance that was initialized like:

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed: @"NSStatusUnavailable"];
```

And you would like to use the image that is mapped to @"NSStatusAvailable".

Without going into details, you really want to assign your image to [NSImage imageNamed: @"NSStatusAvailable"];

Take a look at the docs for NSImage.  Specifically what you might find useful is the imageNamed: class method.

> Discussion
>   This method searches for named images in several places, returning the first image it finds matching the given name. The order of the search is as follows:
>
> Search for an object whose name was set explicitly using the setName: method and currently >resides in the image cache.
>   Search the app's main bundle for a file whose name matches the specified string. (For information on how the bundle is searched, see ““Accessing a Bundle's Contents”“ in >Bundle Programming Guide.)
>   Search the Application Kit framework for a shared image with the specified name.

But also since you're new, just reviewing Objective-C docs on object life cycle will be very useful to understand what's going on.

Comment: No, I didn't initialize the image like that, I have an outlet to update the image, and the code you gave me doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I changed it to self.image.image and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
let ️ = NSImage(named: .statusAvailable)
let ️ = NSImage(named: .statusPartiallyAvailable)
let  = NSImage(named: .statusUnavailable)
let  = NSImage(named: .statusNone)
```